# Turning bit type into a dropdownlistfor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, razor

I have a `BIT` type in a `sql database` that I want to turn into a `DropDownList`.

I pass a model to the page which has an `active` field.  This field is either true or false.  I'm adding the ability to modify this column in the database.

Is it possible to create a `DropDownListFor` that will give them the option of `"Active" "Disable"` and then return the correct value to the database?

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.active, ??)

@Model.active
```

Comment: Does it need to be a dropdown? Can it be checkbox?

Comment: @Guillelon I suppose a check box would work just fine.

Comment: If it's a non-nullable bit field, you can get a checkbox with just @Html.EditorFor(m=>m.active)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have never tried this but how about this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m=> m.active, new List<SelectListItem>() { new SelectListItem { Text = "Active", Value = "true", Selected = Model.active }, new SelectListItem { Text = "Inactive", Value = "false", Selected = Model.active } })
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution works great.  The only thing I had to change for my code is the "Selected" value if the model value is "False"

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m=> m.active, new List<SelectListItem>() { new SelectListItem { Text = "Active", Value = "true", Selected = Model.active }, new SelectListItem { Text = "Inactive", Value = "false", Selected = !Model.active } })
```

It was displaying Active even though it should display Inactive.